# MYSQL Count entries and group by two criteria with output in to a 2d table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a table that looks something like this;
(actual table is larger with several million rows)

Test_table

```
ID  Day Value
=============
1   1   4
2   1   -1
3   1   27
4   1   3
5   1   -2
6   1   -5
7   1   3
8   1   1
9   1   1
10  1   Null
11  2   1
12  2   1
13  2   2
14  2   -1
15  2   -3
```

I want to produce a table of these two columns with the count of the number of times each entry appears, a 2d table with the day down the rows, and the values across the top with each cell containing the count of entries in that criteria like the below;

Desired output

```
Day    Null -5  -3  -2  -1  1   2   3   4   27
==================================================================================
1      1     1       1   1  2       2   1   1
2                1       1  2   1
```

A query like;

```
select day, value, count(*) as count 
    from test_Table 
    group by day, value 
    Order by day asc,  value desc
;
```

produces the data as many rows and only 3 columns...  How can I get the desired output?

Comment: multiple answers here search on pivot table  mysql. but i don't think this will work if you have a lot of unique values in the column Value

Comment: @RaymondN Thanks, yes that the sort of thing I am after.

Comment: is Null -5  -3  -2  -1  1   2   3   4   27   fixed? or could there be more values? if they are fixed then you could use Gordon Linoff SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select day,
       sum(value is NULL) as "NULL",
       sum(value = -5) as "-5",
       sum(value = -3) as "-3",
       sum(value = -2) as "-2",
       sum(value = -1) as "-1",
       sum(value = 1) as "1",
       sum(value = 2) as "2",
       sum(value = 3) as "3",
       sum(value = 4) as "4",
       sum(value = 27) as "27"
from test_Table 
group by day
Order by day asc;
```

Note two things.  First, the column values are fixed.  If you want dynamic column names, then you need to use dynamic SQL.  Second, instead of blanks this will have `0` for the days with no count of a particular value.

Comment: Thanks.  For days with no count of a particular value 0 is fine.  The problem is it the column names could be pretty much any int...  I guess I am going to have to investigate dynamic SQL...  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it can't be done in MySQL.

The reason is that a SELECT statement has to specify the number of columns to be returned, a name and datatype for each column. And MySQL cannot dynamically generate columns to be returned for you.

The longer answer is that you would need a query of the form:

```
SELECT t.Day
     , SUM(IF(t.value IS NULL,1,0)) AS `Null`
     , SUM(IF(t.value = -5   ,1,0)  AS `-5`
     , SUM(IF(t.value = -3   ,1,0)  AS `-3`
     , ...
  FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.Day
```

with each column specified in the SELECT list.

One trick you can use is to use another, separate query to help write that query you need. This has to be a separate step, a separate query. To get the list of values you want returned as column headers would be of the form:

```
SELECT IFNULL(v.value,'Null') AS val
  FROM mytable v
 GROUP BY v.value
 ORDER BY IF(v.value IS NULL,0,1), v.value
```

If you are doing this just in MySQL (and not an application), you can have MySQL help generate the required SQL text for you (using SQL to generate SQL)

```
SELECT CONCAT('     , SUM(IF(t.value',
         IFNULL(v.value,' IS NULL',CONCAT(' = ',v.value)),
         ',1,0)) AS `',v.value,'`'
       ) AS expr
  FROM mytable v
 GROUP BY v.value
 ORDER BY IF(v.value IS NULL,0,1), v.value
```

Then copy the string values returned from the `expr` column, paste those into an editor, and finish creating the SQL statement, like the example shown above.

---

The answer from Gordon shows the expression `IF(col=12,1,0)` can be abbreviated to `col=12`.

I always find myself typing that out the `IF(conditional,valtrue,valfalse)`, but that's just the way my brain works. It's just easier for me to read.

Similarly the expression in the `ORDER BY` in my example...

```
ORDER BY IF(v.value IS NULL,0,1)
```

could be rewritten...

```
ORDER BY v.value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it can been done by using a very hacky way with prepared statement and group by  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: @Raymond N: yes, that is the same approach. It's using SQL to generate a SQL statement, and then executing that SQL statement.

Comment: @user26756706: pulling the data into Excel, and creating the pivot table there is usually what I do.

Comment: @spencer7593: I was just thinking how easy this would be to do in excel... Was trying desperately to avoid that though.